# JOIN Issue : Correct the SQL Statement to solve : ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join

As you see below; how can I implement fx.ftf_validitystartdate= ... this lines value since oracle does not allow me to do it like this below
.

```
    select * from  acc_accounts acc
    join kp_paramcore p on
    acc.account_no = p.accountnum
    acc.suffix = p.suffixc
         LEFT JOIN ftf_rates fx
              ON p.maturestart = fx.ftf_vadealtsinir
             AND p.maturefinish = fx.ftf_vadeustsinir
             AND fx.statusrec = 'A'
             AND fx.currencycode = acc.currencsw_kod
             AND fx.status= 'A' 
  and  fx.ftf_validitystartdate= (SELECT MAX(ff.ftf_validitystartdate)
                                               FROM ftf_rates ff
                                              WHERE ff.status = 'A'
                                                AND ff.statusrec = 'A'
                                                AND v_CurrentDate BETWEEN ff.systemstartdate AND ff.systemfinishdate                                            AND ff.currencycode = acc.currencsw_kod
    )
```

Comment: `And` missing after `fx.status= 'A'` in your copy-paste query?

Comment: oracle version 10g and must work also on 11g

Comment: I assume you're missing an `on` as well after the `kp_paramcore` join?

Comment: fixed. thank you. Sorry for the missed parts since I only focused to express the line where I get the error.

Comment: Sorry, I can't post an answer for you. Perhaps CTE expressions can words but I don't try it because CTE is only availabre from 11g. You can try to create a view as the doc suggests.

Comment: @danihp: CTEs were available long before Oracle 11g (I think they were introducted in 9.1 maybe even earlier - but they are definitely available in 10.x). 11.2 introduced **recursive** CTEs which is not needed in this case.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, please, review my answer. Thanks to correct my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I publish the workaround with CTE and tested only in Oracle 11g.

[To make test I create this schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bd9cb/9/0):

```
create table t_a ( a int );
create table t_b ( a int);
create table t_c ( a int);

insert into t_a values (1);
insert into t_a values (2);
insert into t_a values (3);

insert into t_b values (1);
insert into t_b values (2);
insert into t_b values (3);

insert into t_c values (1);
insert into t_c values (2);
insert into t_c values (3);
```

At this time I force error with this query:

```
select * 
from t_a
left outer join t_b
  on t_a.a = t_b.a and
     t_b.a = ( select max( a )
             from t_c);
```

And now I rewrite query with CTE:

```
with cte (a ) as (
   select a
   from t_b
   where t_b.a = ( select min( a )
             from t_c)
)
select * 
from t_a
left outer join cte
  on t_a.a = cte.a;
```

This second query returns right results.

I rewrite your query with CTE:

```
with CTE as (
   select * from ftf_rates 
   where ftf_validitystartdate= (SELECT MAX(ff.ftf_validitystartdate)
                                 FROM ftf_rates ff
                                 WHERE ff.status = 'A'
                                      AND ff.statusrec = 'A'
                                      AND v_CurrentDate BETWEEN ff.systemstartdate 
                                      AND ff.systemfinishdate                   
                                      AND ff.currencycode = acc.currencsw_kod )

)
    select * from  acc_accounts acc
    join kp_paramcore p on
    acc.account_no = p.accountnum
    acc.suffix = p.suffixc
         LEFT JOIN CTE fx
              ON p.maturestart = fx.ftf_vadealtsinir
             AND p.maturefinish = fx.ftf_vadeustsinir
             AND fx.statusrec = 'A'
             AND fx.currencycode = acc.currencsw_kod
             AND fx.status= 'A'
```

Notice, only tested in Oracle 11g. See @a_horse_with_no_name coment:

> @danihp: CTEs were available long before Oracle 11g (I think they were
>   introducted in 9.1 maybe even earlier - but they are definitely
>   available in 10.x). 11.2 introduced recursive CTEs which is not needed
>   in this case. –

Answer (score 5):

It should work if you switch this to a `where` clause:

```
select *
from acc_accounts acc join
     kp_paramcore p
     on acc.account_no = p.accountnum and
        acc.suffix = p.suffixc LEFT JOIN
     ftf_rates fx
     ON p.maturestart = fx.ftf_vadealtsinir and
        p.maturefinish = fx.ftf_vadeustsinir and
        fx.statusrec = 'A' and
        fx.currencycode = acc.currencsw_kod and
        fx.status= 'A'
 where fx.ftf_validitystartdate= (SELECT MAX(ff.ftf_validitystartdate)
                                 FROM ftf_rates ff
                                 WHERE ff.status = 'A' and
                                       ff.statusrec = 'A'
                                       p.v_CurrentDate BETWEEN ff.systemstartdate AND ff.systemfinishdate                                            AND ff.currencycode = acc.currencsw_kod
                                )
```

However, you lose the 'left outer join' characteristics, so you would also want to add:  `or fx.ftf_validitystartdate is null`.  I guess that v_CurrentDate comes from "p".  It is always a good idea to use table aliases before column names.

However, I question whether the subquery is really needed.  It is only needed when there is more than one record that meets the conditions inside the subquery.  Otherwise, I think you can just change the `on` clause to be:

```
    ON p.maturestart = fx.ftf_vadealtsinir and
       p.maturefinish = fx.ftf_vadeustsinir and
       fx.statusrec = 'A' and
       fx.currencycode = acc.currencsw_kod and
       fx.status= 'A'and
       p.v_CurrentDate BETWEEN fx.systemstartdate AND fx.systemfinishdate
```