# Oracle Query ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I written a query that worked for weeks but this morning I am getting the following error on my Select Inner Join

> ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery

Here is my query

```
SELECT 
     PERSON.PERSONID, 
     PERSON.LASTNAME, 
     PERSON.FIRSTNAME, 
     PERSON.MIDDLENAME,


FROM PERSON_VIEW PERSON
LEFT JOIN (SELECT PERSONID, DRIVERLICENSE_NUM, DRIVERLICENSE_EXP_DT,UPDATED_DT  
                        FROM DRIVERLICENSE_VIEW) DRIVERLICENSE
ON DRIVERLICENSE.PERSONID = PERSON.PERSONID AND 
       ((trunc(sysdate) - DRIVERLICENSE.UPDATED_DT <= 1000)) AND
       DRIVERLICENSE_EXP_DT = (SELECT MAX(DRIVERLICENSE_EXP_DT)   
                               FROM DRIVERLICENSE_VIEW PPT
                               WHERE PPT.PERSONID = DRIVERLICENSE_VIEW.PERSONID)
```

When I removed the inner query, it works but this was working for a few weeks.

```
DRIVERLICENSE_EXP_DT = (SELECT MAX(DRIVERLICENSE_EXP_DT)   
                        FROM DRIVERLICENSE_VIEW PPT
                        WHERE PPT.PERSONID = DRIVERLICENSE_VIEW.PERSONID)
```

How do I fix this query to work again?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that query had worked earlier coz am sure it wouldnt have run ever coz it has errors. Check 5th line of the query you posted.

Comment: the usual recipe here is to persist the subquery as a view, then join that view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JOIN Issue : Correct the SQL Statement to solve : ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911273/join-issue-correct-the-sql-statement-to-solve-ora-01799-a-column-may-not-be)

Comment: As pointed out by @Raj_Te, there is no way that the query just *suddenly* started producing this error.  If it was working before, then it must have been a different query.

Comment: Are you sure you (or someone/something) didn't change that subquery? What does the WHERE clause do? You have PPT on the LHS and DRIVERLICENSE_VIEW on the RHS, but in the line just above you defined PPT to be another name for DRIVERLICENSE_VIEW... are you just testing for not-null values in personid? Because that's all the WHERE clause does. Or is this a modified version of your actual query?

Comment: @sstan - other than the same error message, I see no similarity to the post from 2012 you linked to. I don't think that alone qualifies as a "duplicate" - did I miss other similarities?

Comment: @mathguy: It seems pretty close to me.. left joining on a table where the join condition is a subquery performing on aggregate on that same table... isn't that the same?

Comment: Perhaps, if the OP's question in this thread was "how can I write the query differently". He is asking what's wrong with the current one. I suspect he must have made some changes, despite what he says; see for example my comment above (the longer one). Although I see your point. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the analytic [`row_number()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) function for identifying the record with the latest expiry date. So add the following expression to the inner select list:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PERSONID ORDER BY DRIVERLICENSE_EXP_DT DESC) AS RN
```

... and then filter the result to `RN = 1` instead of the subquery check:

```
SELECT    PERSON.PERSONID, 
          PERSON.LASTNAME, 
          PERSON.FIRSTNAME, 
          PERSON.MIDDLENAME,
          DRIVERLICENSE.DRIVERLICENSE_NUM, 
          DRIVERLICENSE.DRIVERLICENSE_EXP_DT,
          DRIVERLICENSE.UPDATED_DT
FROM      PERSON_VIEW PERSON
LEFT JOIN (SELECT PERSONID, 
                  DRIVERLICENSE_NUM, 
                  DRIVERLICENSE_EXP_DT,
                  UPDATED_DT,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PERSONID 
                                     ORDER BY DRIVERLICENSE_EXP_DT DESC) AS RN
           FROM   DRIVERLICENSE_VIEW) DRIVERLICENSE
        ON DRIVERLICENSE.PERSONID = PERSON.PERSONID
       AND trunc(sysdate) - DRIVERLICENSE.UPDATED_DT <= 1000
       AND RN = 1
```

I also expect you could get a few more non-null driver license results that could be of interest, if you would move the `sysdate` test inside the subquery -- but it all depends on what you want to achieve:

```
SELECT    PERSON.PERSONID, 
          PERSON.LASTNAME, 
          PERSON.FIRSTNAME, 
          PERSON.MIDDLENAME,
          DRIVERLICENSE.DRIVERLICENSE_NUM, 
          DRIVERLICENSE.DRIVERLICENSE_EXP_DT,
          DRIVERLICENSE.UPDATED_DT
FROM      PERSON_VIEW PERSON
LEFT JOIN (SELECT PERSONID, 
                  DRIVERLICENSE_NUM, 
                  DRIVERLICENSE_EXP_DT,
                  UPDATED_DT,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PERSONID 
                                     ORDER BY DRIVERLICENSE_EXP_DT DESC) AS RN
           FROM   DRIVERLICENSE_VIEW
           WHERE  trunc(sysdate) - UPDATED_DT <= 1000) DRIVERLICENSE
        ON DRIVERLICENSE.PERSONID = PERSON.PERSONID
       AND RN = 1
```

Finally, I suppose you are also selecting some fields from `driverlicense` in your main `select`, otherwise there is little use in performing the `left join`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT   
 PERSON.PERSONID,   
 PERSON.LASTNAME,  
 PERSON.FIRSTNAME,  
 PERSON.MIDDLENAME  
FROM PERSON_VIEW PERSON  
LEFT JOIN (SELECT PERSONID,  
    DRIVERLICENSE_NUM,  
    DRIVERLICENSE_EXP_DT,  
    UPDATED_DT    
    FROM DRIVERLICENSE_VIEW) DRIVERLICENSE  
ON DRIVERLICENSE.PERSONID = PERSON.PERSONID  
    AND ((trunc(SYSDATE) - DRIVERLICENSE.UPDATED_DT <= 1000))  
    AND DRIVERLICENSE_EXP_DT = (SELECT MAX(DRIVERLICENSE_EXP_DT)   
                            FROM   DRIVERLICENSE_VIEW PPT  
                            WHERE PPT.PERSONID = DRIVERLICENSE.PERSONID)
```

You have an error in the last line as you don't have any object DRIVERLICENSE_VIEW in the query, you have alias that as DRIVERLICENSE. I hope this will work.

You can use directly table instead of sub query in left join because and it works in the same manner:

```
SELECT 
 PERSON.PERSONID, 
 PERSON.LASTNAME, 
 PERSON.FIRSTNAME, 
 PERSON.MIDDLENAME
FROM PERSON_VIEW PERSON
LEFT JOIN DRIVERLICENSE_VIEW DRIVERLICENSE ON DRIVERLICENSE.PERSONID = PERSON.PERSONID 
AND ((trunc(SYSDATE) - DRIVERLICENSE.UPDATED_DT <= 1000))
AND DRIVERLICENSE_EXP_DT = (SELECT MAX(DRIVERLICENSE_EXP_DT)   
       FROM DRIVERLICENSE_VIEW PPT WHERE PPT.PERSONID = DRIVERLICENSE.PERSONID)
```